# Database Querying function not running asynchronously

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous

So I created a function in my node server which takes in a query string, runs it on my db, and returns the results. I then wanted to use my function asynchronously using async await throughout my routes instead of having nested query within, nested query, within nested query etc.

So here is the code:

```
 const runQuery = queryString => {
    console.log("...runQuery")
    db.query(queryString, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("runQuery: FAILURE");
            return error;
        }
        else {
            console.log("runQuery: SUCCESS");
            return(results);
        }
    })
}

register.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const results = await runQuery("select * from test1");
    res.send(results);
})
```

The database should have 3 entries, but unfortunately, it returns nothing. Meaning results is an empty variable when it is sent, meaning JS never properly waits for it to capture the db results. How can I use my function asynchronously, and how is this even feasible?

Comment: what is your `db` object?

Comment: its a basic mysql connection object i imported from another file.

Comment: I know it's a connection object. When people ask, we usually mean put the code as well or describe it like for example `mysql` from package `some-pacakge`. You're trying to use `Promise` but not all package provides promise support

Comment: Ahhh I see. Apologies about that. But yes I checked the problem again today and see that the mysql package doesn't have promise support. my db connection is from the regular mysql package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your function "runQuery" does not return a promise, in fact, it's not returning anything. You are using "return" in the callback of the db.query function, not the function "runQuery" itself.

Since runQuery is performing an asynchronous operation, the result ought to be resolved via a promise (which is what the "await" in your request handler is looking for).

I'm not exactly sure but it seems you are using MySql, and I could not find anything on the npm page of the mysql package regarding the query being promisified, so we'll promisify it ourselves:

```
const runQuery = (queryString) => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    console.log("...runQuery")
    db.query(queryString, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error("runQuery: FAILURE");
            reject(error);
        } else {
            console.log("runQuery: SUCCESS");
            resolve(results);
        }
    })

})

register.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    try{
        const results = await runQuery("select * from test1");
        res.send(results);
    }catch(e){
        console.error(`ERROR THROWN BY runQuery:`,e);
        res.status(500).send({
            message: e.message || "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
        })
    }
})
```

Note that if an error occurs, our promisified function will reject the error and it will NOT be stored in the "results" variable in our request handler. Instead, an error will be thrown which needs to be handled. Therefore, it is **always** a good practice to put any async/await calls inside a try/catch.

Comment: Thanks so much Anuj, your answer worked and taught me something about promises! My apologies for not mentioning that I was using the basic mysql package. It turns out, as another user mentioned, that not all packages support promises. I assumed all db-management packages had promise wrappers automatically applied.

I am an intern so this is all sort of new to me but your answer has helped show me a new dynamic way to use the Promise JS class. Thank so much. Unfortunately, my rep is too low to upvote, otherwise you woulda gotten one. Sorry :(

Comment: You're welcome! It's ok, we're all here to learn. Keep coding!